# Issue with JQuery Image Rotator

Tags: jquery, html, css, vb.net

I have an image rotator that was created using JQuery, but when it runs I'm getting an error message that says Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object Expected.  Here is the code that I'm using.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#nav { margin: 20px auto }
#nav a { padding: 4px 6px; margin: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ddd }
#nav a.activeSlide { color: #c00 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }

.slideshow { margin: 20px auto; padding: 0; clear: left; }
.slide { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
.slideshow, .slide { height: 232px; width: 710px; }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; margin: 0 }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        timeout: 0,
        pager: '#nav'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:auto;text-align:center"><div id="nav"></div></div>
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200"  height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Images/Get Inspired/ThumbNails/Th.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me, just delete following:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

hope it helps...